# Stanford CoreNLP missing caseless models in archive

Tags: stanford-nlp

Version 3.9.1 here. The caseless models fails to load because it cannot find the pos-model

```
"edu.stanford.nlp.models.pos-tagger.english-caseless-left3words-distsim.tagger"
```

Looking inside the models jar, i find that  path

```
"\edu\stanford\nlp\models\pos-tagger"
```

is followed  by

```
"english-left3words"
```

and the "caseless" path is missing.
But according to docs,

> Starting with version 3.6, caseless models for English are included in the new comprehensive english jar file.

I can't seem to find the caseless model anywhere in the distribution. Am I missing something? I am setting up an example as published on the Caseless [models page](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/caseless.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need the full English models jar, rather than the models jar included in the archive (which only contains the most commonly used models). You can find the model under "Language: English" in the models jar download table at: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#download.

Comment: Many thanks. I am still getting the message "edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)." Do I need to download the KBK jar also?

Comment: My guess is that you have not set up your classpath correctly. What is the command you're using to start the program?

Comment: args= ["java", "-cp","f:/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27/*", "-Xmx4g", "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer", "-port", "9000"]
p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdout=None, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print (p.returncode, p.pid). This works; i am getting perfect results from the mixed case scenarios. It is only the lower case text which is running afoul.

Comment: Did you move the full models jar into that directory for your classpath